# My computer will not boot after an upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10. It used to only work in nVidia Optimus, now it will not boot at all

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I have an Ubuntu Thinkpad W530 with an Nvidia K2000 graphics card.

I am dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

A long time ago, all of this worked perfectly so I know it is possible. However, recently I foolishly updated the version of Ubuntu I was running to 19.04.

When I did this, I could no longer boot into Ubuntu, unless the BIOS was set to `Nvidia Optimus Mode`.

[image]

I don't think this actually put my machine in Optimus mode but it did make the graphics card work.

Hoping to fix this, I upgraded to 19.10, but that just broke everything.  Now I can not consistently boot into Ubuntu no matter what I do. The screen usually hangs with light purple background or just shows a very fast blinker at the top left.

Things I have tried:

- Setting and unsetting `nomodeset` in the GRUB boot commands
- Using the Nvidia 390 driver and Nouveau driver (no change)
- setting acpi=off in GRUB boot commands (this works, but no external monitors work)
- Setting graphics card to `Integrated Graphics` in this BIOS (this works but no external monitors)
- Updating the BIOS firmware (even though this used to work fine)

Previously this computer ran with `Discrete Graphics` set to on.  My Windows partition works fine.

Occasionally I see the following errors:
[image]

Approximately one out of 16 boots this works as is, so I know it can be done.  It feels like there is an issue with the graphics card talking to X but setting `nomodeset` does not help.

I have noticed that for Nvidia Optimus mode my laptop screen does not work, but if I unplug and plug in an external monitor, I can get that display to work.

I am using the latest recommended Nvidia driver (430).  Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I have a simlilar issue, happens every time Ubuntu updates system files under 19.10.
I get a purple screen at login without the login prompt. I found out that the Nvidia card at boot switches to a hypothetical second screen, sets it as primary and shows only the secondary. When I move the mouse to the right, the mouse pointer appears coming from the left side of the screen - hence there is a second screen to the left of my laptop that I can't see.
But I can access it, typing

Enter
My password
Enter

and Ubuntu starts normally. the first time it happened it also showed me a blank desktop since also in GUI the primary desktop was the not-connected second screen. Accessing the screen options via shortcut (Fn - Fsomething) restored the single screen. i the changed the screen options to single screen again and I'm safe until the next update.